# Simpler way to pass multiple parameters of same type in constructor?

Tags: c#, types, parameters, constructor, xna

Here's what I have to do;

```
public weapon(Texture2D knife, Texture2D pistol, Texture2D smg, Texture2D rifle,
SoundEffect knifeStab, SoundEffect pistolShot, SoundEffect smgShot, SoundEffect rifleShot)
{
}
```

Here's what I'd really like to do;

```
public weapon(Texture2D [knife, pistol, smg, rifle], 
SoundEffect [knifeStab, pistolShot, smgShot, rifleShot])
{
}
```

Is there something like that?
Would it be easier to send them all in a list/array of Texture2D's?

Comment: That doesn't look like a substantial improvement.  Can you wrap all of your parameters into a single object?  You'll get better visibility on this question if you tag it with the language that you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a quicker way to pass parameters, that's all.
I could create a list called "TextureBulk", which means I may have answered my own question if you see the last sentence of the main post. I was just curious as to whether or not C# provided a simple way to pass parameters of the same time.

If you consider how you can declare variables like this;

    **int x, y, z;**

then you may understand why I assumed there would be an equivalent way to pass parameters.

Comment: Why do you need a knife *AND* a pistol *AND* an smg *AND* a rifle to construct a weapon?  Shouldn't you just need *one* of those (with a corresponding sound effect) not one of *each*?

Comment: These weapons will be exclusive to the player object, and the player will have its own weapon. I'm chucking all the weapon-related business into the weapon class so it can manage its own sound effects and textures. It all relies upon an enum (weaponState) to play the required sound and draw the required texture.

Comment: Are you looking to make the `weapon()` declaration shorter, or the passing of the parameters shorter?  Because I can think of many ways to do the former, but no ways to do the latter.

Comment: When I declare new objects in XNA, I'm always typing 'Content.Load<type>("name.format")' for each parameter despite them all being of the same type.

Comment: I know, there is not you ask, but let me ask: Can a Weapon, be a knife and a pistol in same object? Because it's not your constructor will be better `weapon(Texture2D knife, SoundEffect knifeStab)`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass multiple arguments to a method, you're basically saying that all of these are important to the method but otherwise unrelated. If that's the case, by all means pass the number of argument you need.

However, in many cases, arguments are related. In your example I imagine that the textures and the sound effects come in pairs. If that's the case, you could use encapsulate to express this.

That would not only reduce the number of arguments, but also keep related data together.

Comment: By encapsulate, you mean putting the textures and sound effects into a list and, for simplicity's sake, only passing one item (the list)?

Comment: It depends. From the naming in your code it looks to me like the texture and the sound effect goes hand-in-hand. If that's the case, you could create a dedicated type to handle this.

Comment: @ShadowByte No, he means constructing an object that has both a sound and a texture to represent both aspects of a rifle, smg, etc.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Many thanks to both of you. Although, considering the amount of code to be written, I may end up writing more code just to provide a class for simpler parameter passing.